# Safely clear (or remove children) of a DivElement

Tags: java, gwt

This is my code to clear the children of a given `DivElement`:

```
    int count = rows.getChildCount();
    for (int i=0 ; i < count; i++){
        Node child = rows.getChild(i);
        rows.removeChild(child);
    }
```

However, I can see that at point it throws:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Child index out of bounds
```

How to safely remove childresn of a `DivElement`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Think about what happens in this loop. Lets take a div with three children:

int count = rows.getChildCount();

At this point, clearly `count` is 3, so we start through the for loop with `i` at zero.

```
Node child = rows.getChild(0);
rows.removeChild(child);
```

Now, `rows` only has 2 items, but count is still 3. Next step through the loop, `i` is one.

```
Node child = rows.getChild(1);
rows.removeChild(child);
```

This is the second item in a list with two items - the last item in the list, but not the final item to remove. As we enter the loop again, `i` is two, but there is only one item left!

```
Node child = rows.getChild(2); // Exception!
```

---

In general, when modifying a list *as* you iterate through it, there are a few good approaches.

- Modify the loop to only increment when you *don't* remove an item. This is a common approach when you need to walk forward (and use the ordering of the list) but only need to remove some items.
- Don't use a `for` loop, but just a `while`, and check if the list is empty - if not, remove the zeroth item. This is useful to walk forward and remove *every* item. Put simply:

  ```
   while (rows.hasChildNode()) {
     rows.removeChild(rows.getFirstChild());
   }
  ```
- Walk the list backward - start with the index as the final item in the list, and subtract one each step. This way, any time you remove an item, you don't need to worry about whether there is a next item, since there is always a previous item, as long as you are above zero!

  ```
  for (int i = count; i >= 0; i--) {
    rows.removeChild(rows.getChild(i));
  }
  ```

A few more that apply especially to HTML:

- Elements contain html - in most cases we can simply call `setInnerHTML("")`. Note that this has issues in IE when dealing with tables.

  ```
  rows.setInnerHTML("");
  ```
- GWT 2.6 has a new method in Element, specifically `Element.removeAllChildren()`. Just call this method on your div element. This method more or less runs the while loop discussed above:

  ```
  rows.removeAllChildren();
  ```

Comment: Ghaa, I want to +10 that answer; how come I can only +1 it?

Comment: Upgrading would be the best solution in my case. Thanks for the tip